# BigQuery with GraphQL

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, graphql

Is it possible to use GraphQL for doing BigQuery Queries? I haven't found a way to do it. I don't know if it would be the correct approach to use GraphQL to query against BigQuery. I'm using Node.js and have a working example with MySQL and Sequelize

What are your recommendations?

Comment: SQL much preferred

Comment: There's not enough information here for anyone to provide recommendations, maybe explain the context in more detail and WHY you are considering using GraphQL with BigQuery.

Comment: I'm just researching if it will be suitable to run queries against BigQuery using GraphQL, is just a Proof of concept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BigQuery is an SQL oriented data-warehouse. Here the key word is data-warehouse, because it's not a database like MySQL: Latency and atomic transaction aren't handled by BigQuery. However it's a powerful tool for analytics and processing TB of data.

I never saw GraphQL implementation for analytics, it was always for real time querying. Sadly, the latency of BigQuery is high (about 1 to 2s before the query start) and thus it's not suitable for real time/website and low latency response time.

That's why, I **can't recommend** you to use BigQuery with GraphQL.

Comment: So you can recommend to use BigQuery with GraphQL? I haven't found any documentation on how to use GraphQL with BigQuery nor anyone that has done it :(

Comment: sorry for my mistake, I can't recommend !! I edited my answer. It's more consistent with my previous description.

Answer (score 0):

A key aspect of GraphQL is that you can map any datasource into it. It is also easy to add caching into it. If you have access to BigQuery then you also have access to BigTable and CloudSQL. You can map any or all of them to GraphQL as appropriate for your use case.

I wrote some example code of using [GraphQL Java](https://www.graphql-java.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-spring-boot/) to query BigQuery over at [quarkus-graphql-bigquery](https://github.com/simbo1905/quarkus-graphql-bigquery). The code caches entities in a Guava cache.

I also wrote some example code of [GraphQL Java querying BigTable](https://github.com/simbo1905/bigtable-graphql). Someone could combine these apps so that they can choose to move entities from being stored in BigQuery to BigTable without changing the schema or any client code.

All of the BigQuery documentation has example code in both Node.js, Java, C#, Go and Python. So it should be easy to connect and map BigQuery into any high-quality GraphQL engine written in any language.

BigQuery is fast enough for doing a certain class of interactive apps. Especially if you add caching into the mapping. Probably the main thing to understand is that as at the beginning of 2021 you are limited to 100 concurrent queries per project. Talking to Google they say that they aim for under 50ms query start-up time. Experimentally I find that the first query after being idle for a while can take over a second per query.

If you are writing internal apps that are looking at analytic data in your warehouse, where you have laid out the data to be efficient to fetch, and where you get good cache hits, then GraphQL could be a good fit. If not then shunt the data over into BigTable (else CloudSQL) and map that into GraphQL.